# In Go Lang Set the Tag for a Whole Struct

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, lang

I'm using Go and GoRestful to program a RESTFUL front end to some entities stored on Google App Engine Datastore.

The data is turned into JSON/XML and presented to the user with tags controlling the style for each format. How can I also apply tags to the name of the struct itself so it is output using the correct style?

An example of my structs would be:

```
type Shallow struct {
    Key          string    `datastore:"-" json:"key" xml:"key"`
    LastModified time.Time `json:"last_modified" xml:"last-modified"`
    Version      int       `json:"version" xml:"version"`
    Status       int       `json:"status" xml:"status"`
    Link         Link      `datastore:"-" json:"link" xml:"link"`
    Name         string    `json:"name" xml:"name"`
}

type ProbabilityEntry struct {
    ItemId      int64   `datastore:"ItemId" json:"item_id" xml:"item-id"`
    Probability float32 `datastore:"Probability" json:"probability" xml:"probability"`
    Quantity    int16   `datastore:"Quantity" json:"quantity" xml:"quantity"`
}

type LootTable struct {
    Shallow
    AllowPreload  bool               `json:"allow_preload" xml:"allow-preload"`
    Probabilities []ProbabilityEntry `json:"probabilities" xml:"probabilities"`
}
```

When the LootTable struct emits to JSON/XML it should represent itself as 'loot_table' or 'loot-table' rather than 'LootTable'.

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using to marshal the LootTable that's producing the output you don't want? A simple call to `json.Marshal(myLootTable)` wouldn't "represent itself" as anything but a json dict.

Comment: The code is opaque to my application, being provided either by GoRestful or some other built in library. Dommage's answer below will cover my needs nicely in any case.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer:

Wrap it in an outer struct:

```
type Payload struct {
   Loot LootTable `json:"loot_table"`
}
```

Longer answer:

If the receiver of the JSON knows what they're getting then this is not really necessary.  However, when building a JSON API I often create a Response struct that contains extra details regarding the request, that could include the type of the response. Here is an example:

```
type JSONResponse struct {
   Obj    interface{} `json:"obj"`    // Marshall'ed JSON (not wrapped)
   Type   string      `json:"type"`   // "loot_table" for example
   Ok     bool        `json:"ok"`     // Does this response require error handling?
   Errors []string    `json:"errors"` // Any errors, you could leave out Ok and just check this
}
```

Again, with API calls you usually know what you're expecting, but if the response could be one of a number of types this approach can help.